# Recibir y recorrer array desde una función

Tags: php, funciones

Buenas me presento con la duda de como recibir un array que es enviado desde una función que se encuentra en otra pagina php a la actual y recorrerlo.

Primero realizo (En Informe.php):

```
$resultado;
switch($Buscar){
    case "1":
        $accion = new Imprimir();
        $accion->setDato($datoBuscar);
        $resultado=$accion->trabajadores();
    break;
}
```

Luego la siguiente acción (Voy a Imprimir.php con la function trabajadores()):

```
public function trabajadores(){
    try{
        $registros=array();
        $conexion=new Conectar();
        $conexion = $conexion->conexion();
        $consulta=$conexion->prepare("SELECT ? FROM trabajador");
        $consulta->bindValue("1", $this->getDato(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $consulta->execute();
        if($consulta->rowCount()>0){
            $registros=$consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo "Error traer checkbox: ".$ex->getMessage();
    }finally{
        $conexion=NULL;
        return $registros;
    }
}
```

Luego lo recorro (En Informe.php):

```
for($d=1; $d<5;$d++){
    $Contenido .= "<tr>";

    for($i=1; $i<$Num+1; $i++){
        $Contenido .= "<td class='content'>".$resultado[$i]."</td>";
    }

    $Contenido .= "</tr>";
}
```

Hay mas procesos entremedio, que se realizan para generar un informe, pero es tema aparte, lo que no comprendo es recibir ese array, recorrerlo y mostrarlo

Solución:

```
foreach($resultado as $r){
    $Contenido .= "<tr>";

        foreach($r as $rd){
            $Contenido .= "<td class='content'>".$rd."</td>";
        }

    $Contenido .= "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: es otra página u otro archivo php? si es entre páginas tendrás que usar sesiones para pasar los datos de una a otra

Comment: Me pillaste con la pregunta de pagina o archivo, dado que no los diferencio, pero uno es donde interactua con la DB y el otro es donde se genera el contenido a imprimir, este segundo llama al primero y lo intenta recorrer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recoger un array utiliza la función `foreach()`

```
foreach($resultado as $r){
    $Contenido .= "<tr><td class='content'>". $r ."</td></tr>";
}
```

¿Es eso lo que necesitabas?